# How to accommodate very large SQL database in Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have a database with a growth of more than 100 Gb per week, and 5 TB yearly.

Since this is financial data, we can't purge it. If we keep this data for at least 10 years, size will become 50 TB.

Please suggest how we can accommodate this amount of data in Azure VMs with limitation of 1 TB disc in Azure.

Comment: I think  contacting support in this case may help

Comment: Why can't you export it to blob storage ? Single blob limit is 5GB.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the solutions that azure has for [big data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749804.aspx), you should be able to store and query that data there.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to Andrew Diamond's answer

Think out of straightforward RDBMS box, they're not for that.

30 sec of googling revealed MS have Data Lake in their Azure right for that.
Go explore it.

Alternatively, there are gazillions of competitors, as-a-service (like, Google BigQuery) or build-it-yourself product based.